# Java algorithm palindrome&

Tags: java, algorithm

```
/**
 * @(#)palindrome1.java
 *
 * palindrome1 application
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 1.00 2013/11/15
 */

public class palindrome1 {

    static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
        int count=0;
        //check all characters of sequence is palindrome
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length();i++)
        {
            if(str.charAt(i)!=str.charAt(str.length()-1-i))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        //if it is return true otherwise return false
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO, add your application code
        String sentence= "bob gave that pop race car to me." ;
        String sentenceMax="";
        String sentenceNew="";

        sentence = sentence.replace( " ","");
        for(int i = 0;i<sentence.length();i++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
            {
                sentenceNew = sentence.substring(k,i);
                if(isPalindrome(sentenceNew)&&sentenceNew.length()>sentenceMax.length());
                {

                sentenceMax=sentenceNew;
                sentenceNew="";
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sentenceMax);
    }
}
```

The question is:t should ask a sentence from user and find the longest palindrome substring in the sentence ignoring the spaces in the sentence and print the longest palindrome substring. You MUST use the function you wrote in Part B. The sentences must be case-insensitive.
and part B is the first method named isPalindrome() in mycode.
The output should be:

```
racecar
```

but my code outputs:

```
e
```

What is wrong at my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have in your code :

```
if(isPalindrome(sentenceNew)&&sentenceNew.length()>sentenceMax.length());
```

And `;` is at the bad place. Since it is there it treats it as a if with an empty block, so your real block `{}` is calculated all the time.

It should be:

```
if(isPalindrome(sentenceNew)&&sentenceNew.length()>sentenceMax.length())
```

Comment: the if top of the sentenceMax=sentenceNew; does include it

Comment: I took a second look ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a new value to sentenceMax each iteration. Try this instead

```
sentenceMax += sentenceNew;
```

Comment: I have to because I want only longest palindrome

Answer (score 0):

Why did you not use the StringBuffer methods ?

StringBuffer.reverse() can reverse the String 
after that you can search each substring in the reverted Source string using StringBuffer.indexOf(subString).

Isnt that a much simpler approach ?

Comment: but this was my lab assignment and we did not learn stringBuffer class but thanks for the advice may be I can use it next labs.

Comment: When you test please test this string 'computers return'.. should it return 'uter' ?

Comment: it returned utersretu which is expected why ?

Comment: Is that expected. That would qualify to be a Palindrom in normal cases. as they are 2 diffrent words. For eg: try 'computers are returned' should it return uters ? May be . Mau be not ? ill let u take the call and decide.

Comment: I created some code here.. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35664/finding-largest-string-palindrome/35710?noredirect=1#35710

Comment: I got what you mean now but I guess our teacher understood wrong meaning of palindrome so I did the code according to that definition  Example palindrome words: civic, kayak, malayalam, wassamassaw.  to him palindrome is a word its reverse and forward spelling is the same but thanks for your attention .